# Have a Generic Type of a Method Depend on the Generic Type Of the Class in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I have a use case that can be expressed in pseudo-code as follows:

```
class Gen<T> {
  public doStuff<U>(input: U 
         /* If T is an instance of number, 
          then input type U should be an instance of custom type ABC, or
          If T is an instance of string,
          then input type U should an instance of custom type XYZ, else
          compile error */) {

     // do stuff with input
  }
}
```

Can this be expressed in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, with inference this is easily feasible. TypeScript allows you to "return" a different type based on a generic input type checking. You should just use a `InferInputType<T>` type like this:

```
type InferInputType<T> =
    T extends number ? ABC :
    T extends string ? XYZ :
    never;
```

then you can rewrite your Gen as:

```
class Gen<T> {
    public doStuff(input: InferInputType<T>) {}
}
```

Then you can use your class like this:

```
const genNumber = new Gen<number>();
genNumber.doStuff({ value: 10 });
genNumber.doStuff({ value: 'abc' }); // Error
```

You can see a working example in the playground: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=46&pln=13&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwEYQE4EkB2Y7CgXigG8oA3AQwBs4IAuKTRFVKAXwChRIoBlYVAJaYA5lhx5CJCtTpQAzvyHC27TuGhYAZmjG4AKuoA8egHwF2US1D1QIAD2ARMAEzkMmaKAH5YHjNlwoWgsrG3tHFzcFQRFvXkURXTxgqwYIUjQAblUAY0pyOTcAcSdjMyIQyxwkSgEcqGcAez44TU0ACiFxei0dAOADSDKASmIODnYcxswFKGEneGRPQkwIAHcoEsxDRiXUE3bh7PnMReYAOiaWtvapKhp6AEYABjYj9hOztEvm4FaOu4yegAcnISBywLemSgAHoYVAAKKoVCNVC5aazE58GLKFbrTalaJKA7vLEJYQ-a4Asj3WTAuwgABekNYpKc2KUlL+N0BDygLyhsPhSJRqCAA)

Comment: I have a similar question, but this time involving generics...Perhaps leonardfactory you have some insights? It is posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61541059/conditional-types-with-generics-in-typescript