# Conditional types with Generics in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics

What I want to achieve can be best explained in code:

Given shoe and dress class:

```
class Shoe {
    constructor(public size: number){}
}
```

```
class Dress {
    constructor(public style: string){}
}
```

Have a generic box that can only contain Shoe or Dress. Can't contain both:

```
class Box <T extends Shoe | Dress > {
}
```

Then have a utility class that takes care of moving shoes:

```
class ShoeMover {
    constructor(public size: number[]){}
}
```

Also, a utility class for moving Dresses:

```
class DressPacker {
    constructor(public style: string[]){}
}
```

Then have a generic mover, that if instantiated with `Box<Shoe>` or `Box<Dress>` has a `mover` method that makes use of either the `ShoeMover` or the `DressPacker`:

```
class Move<B extends Box<Shoe> | Box<Dress>> {
    private box: B;
    constructor(toMove: B) {
        this.box = toMove;
    }
    public mover(tool: ShoeMover | DressPacker) {
    }
}
```

Then the compile time guarantee should be that, if `Move` is instantiated with `Box<Shoe>`, then the `mover` method should only accept `ShoeMover`. If instantiated with `Box<Dress>`. the `mover` method should only accept `DressPacker`. That is:

```
let shoemover = new Move(new Box<Shoe>());

// compile
shoemover.mover(new ShoeMover([21]))

// should not compile. But currently does
shoemover.mover(new DressPacker(["1"]))
```

I tried using conditional types, but I guess the fact that generics is involved makes the intended solution not to work. Basically this is what I have tried:

```
type MoverFromEitherShoeOrDressA<T> =
    T extends Box<infer U> ?
        U extends Shoe ? ShoeMover :
        U extends Dress ? DressPacker :
        never:
    never;

and 

type MoverFromEitherShoeOrDressB<T> =
    T extends Box<Shoe> ? ShoeMover:
    T extends Box<Dress> ? DressPacker:
never;
```

Then changing the definition of `mover` from:

```
public mover(tool: ShoeMover | DressPacker) {
}
```

to

```
public mover(tool: MoverFromEitherShoeOrDressB) {
}

or 

public mover(tool: MoverFromEitherShoeOrDressA) {
}
```

..but these did not give the compile time guarantees that I sought.

Anyone knows how to achieve this?

**Edit.**

The accepted answer works for the scenario above. But there is a slightly different scenario which does not work. Instead of creating another question, I decided to update. The scenario is when the constructor of the `Move` is changed to take in union type.

```
type Mover<T> = 
  T extends Shoe ? ShoeMover : 
  T extends Dress ? DressPacker : 
  never; 

class Move<T extends Shoe | Dress> {
    private box: Box<T>;
    constructor(public toMove: Box<Shoe>[] | Box<Dress>[]) {
        this.box = toMove;
    }
    public mover(tool: Mover<T>) {
    }
}


let shoemover = new Move(new Array<Box<Shoe>>());

// compile
shoemover.mover(new ShoeMover([21]))

// should not compile. But currently does
shoemover.mover(new DressPacker(["1"]))
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKAWB7AptA3gKGt6xEDsIAXAJwFdgjESAKABzICMQBLYaCFgL2QC5p8ZALaNkJAJRoAvhhmhIMACIlkUdFhx5CpClVoNmbDkQCeIPsZIt8Ac0ky54NQCFEAD2gAeACrRkbomR8ABMYBBRoAB9oZVUYAD51GQB6ZOhveCDoeDAAN1QwaDIiFlZTXCcYIhyiaCIwAGtVXDAVaEQAM2ghRFzrGw4kVV4MDHk1cOQAWV6xdRxcAmJySmp6JlZ2Th5+QRExAG0AXXtZDFToAEEQCEQAGmhC4tKWcvGYDupu3v6YlShhqN3n84gAFMDAJokeaaJY6Vb6DZGYhmCzLfrHU4yDCmOioGb5Eg+RIAXmgGl8-kCITCQ2gAH44EMCXN+BS-AEgqEQWpGbEoODIazydh8MhCQBucljSrQFk+DnU7mTKI8iCJTALOhWXJgQLQRjufiuNzEiUabBaZa6NYGTZ1RAs43uTyTeLHVUmzz89WYmELbDVFgQAB0ho8ZKoLPNCxkWqR7B6hJoVEQIH4LKJ3ni4n90Acoww5lqECGSbmZLFAHc5bMaNWriQSGATJ4vW74jRxOJzec0nghHRSsgMKWUOWSCGJ-XkDXJpmaAcAEwARhO4lGFzHZBAwQEiFqA6H5hD0GcxVwZCbQSIIBM0GCKAgo7Ls0n04bPsFUMXACIV7+64YEAA)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You were almost there, you just need to use generics in the `mover` method too, elseway it will not know what `T` is is. See the generic type as a method which takes a generic T as a parameter, and `<>` as `()`:

```
type Mover<T> = 
  T extends Shoe ? ShoeMover : 
  T extends Dress ? DressPacker : 
  never; 

class Move<T extends Shoe | Dress> {
    private box: Box<T>;
    constructor(toMove: Box<T>) {
        this.box = toMove;
    }
    public mover(tool: Mover<T>) {
    }
}
```

Furthermore, I changed the `Move` definition to exclude the `Box` generic since you can easily encapsulate it in the class inner definitions, but your solution would work too with:

```
type MoverFromEitherShoeOrDressA<T> =
    T extends Box<infer U> ?
        U extends Shoe ? ShoeMover :
        U extends Dress ? DressPacker :
        never:
    never;

public mover(tool: MoverFromEitherShoeOrDressA<B>) { // <-- Here
}
```

Edit: added playground here: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKAWB7AptA3gKGt6xEDsIAXAJwFdgjESAKABzICMQBLYaCFgL2QC5p8ZALaNkJAJRoAvhhmhIMACIlkUdFhx5CpClVoNmbDkQCeIPsZIt8Ac0ky54NQCFEAD2gAeACrRkbomR8ABMYBBRoAB9oZVUYAD51GQB6ZOhveCDoeDAAN1QwaDIiFlZTXCcYIhyiaCIwAGtVXDAVaEQAM2ghRFzrGw4kVV4MDHk1cOQAWV6xdRxcAmJySmp6JlZ2Th5+QRExAG0AXXtZDFToAEEQCEQAGmhC4tKWcvGYDupu3v6YlShhqN3n84gAFMDAJokeaaJY6Vb6DZGYhmCzLfrHU4yDCmOioGb5Eg+RIAXmgGl8-kCITCQ2gAH44EMCXN+BS-AEgqEQWpGbEoODIazydh8MhCQBucljSrQFk+DnU7mTKI8iCJTALOhWXJgQLQRjufiuNzEiUabBaZa6NZUFnG9zE8QwhbYaosCAAOkNHjJdtm5oWMi1SPYPUJNCoiBA-BZRO88WdmpwDlG5lqECG4bmZLFAHc5bMaPnoCbPJN4jRxOJzec0nghHRSsgMJmUNmSJ6O8XkAXJnGaAcAEwARhO4lGFzbZBAwQEiFqDab5k9peKuDIJBU+CIIBM0GCKAgrazs073ZL-Iggqhg4ARCO7+OMEA)

Comment: As always I was not patient enough to reproduce the exact problem I have. The exact situation involves  see `move` constructor being like this: `constructor(public toMove: Box<Shoe>[] | Box<Dress>[])` // because move can move multiple boxes of Box of shoes or Box of dress.

Comment: @FinlayWeber add addition information to your question, not to the answer.