# Typescript: Infering class members type

Tags: typescript, generics, conditional-types

I have two types that have a member that is a function called "action". The argument type of the action function depends on the class:

```
type Class_a = {
    action: (arg: string) => string
} 
type Class_b = {
    action: (arg: number) => string
}
```

I want to have a class which can handle the two classes. To do so, I define an union type:

```
type EitherClass = Class_a | Class_b;
```

And I have a type that infer the argument type depending on the class (as explained in this answer: [Have a Generic Type of a Method Depend on the Generic Type Of the Class in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61443338/have-a-generic-type-of-a-method-depend-on-the-generic-type-of-the-class-in-types?noredirect=1&lq=1))

```
type ConditionalArg<T> = T extends Class_a ? string :
                         T extends Class_b ? number :
                         never;
```

However, I get a compile error when I use it in another class with generic type:

```
class MyClass<T extends EitherClass>
{
     public my_type: T;
     public my_arg: ConditionalArg<T>;

     public constructor(my_type: T, my_arg: ConditionalArg<T>)
     {
          this.my_type = my_type;
          this.my_arg = my_arg;
     }

     public do_action(): string
     {
          return this.my_type.action(this.my_arg); // Compile error here 
     }
}
```

I get the following error:
Argument of type 'ConditionalArg' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

The inference works when invoking constructor

```
let inst_a: Class_a = {action: (arg: string) => arg}
let inst_b: Class_b = {action: (arg: number) => arg.toString()}

let class_a_one = new MyClass(inst_a, "B") // compile
let class_a_two = new MyClass(inst_a, 3)  // do not compile
let class_b_one = new MyClass(inst_b, "B") // do not compile
let class_b_two = new MyClass(inst_b, 3) // compile
```

However, the inference doesn't work in the "do_action" method. Is there a workaround to avoid the error ?

Here is a working example in the playground: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgQwM5IPoKgXgFAG9tRQIDGwAlgPYB2AXFABQIBOA5nUsE2VSwJRYA%20KBy49sAX2zZQkWIhSoARljwEipSrQbM2UKgFcAtoohN%20mISO4sJUmdACiZYAAtT8ZEixzP6KAB8fBUUAbmlwaBhqABNnTQQ4AEFWAB4AFSFMKDSoCAAPYAgqaK8PBQwAfmFOaygaNUJGpuaWxpz8wuLS%20TRlKoNjUzqG1tHWqggAN1Mwsbnm7GIeqABZEDKkdNyCopKoJ1d3HoFVQjB9RTgyYihDEFR7OjTZqHPL69v7nToo4rjqBLJFjpARhNRvK43YjUET6UgUJj0O4PCJPAA0n3QrB%20MX%20VEBqQyvDU%20CarjISAAdMj7N4aREXoRyVTkTo6V9WC9JOCLpCoNEKOgNNR6Lx2DUxIRSU0mBBgPomFQoMzqfd7JSSOQRSrWaxeCEoAB6Q38ih6CjAKDQwxgMhwCBqSTiKBSe2W7gcdA-Hp%20LK4TWaOiMbHVUR8QREViSN1QD3AJTe3zKP0B6hB756IwmMwRnSU4AUADKEpYoujcqtPoQqGo0CyEwA7qt1j16HH0BiAEQAIU7-GNVooNrtDoHMaWvmrwAbZvrECbaw2baonoQGIAzPwjSaBebLdbbfbsGOKxPgjWJt5G82l%203FF3e-2d2aqBbB8Oj%20OfYoHjOr-Ob1bO8Nyfd9DwdRYYQoe1KTgChSzPNBq1rSkBSFLUqFFYlsCAA)

Comment: Is the following good enough? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgQQMbDgewHYB4AqAfFALxQDeAUFFAIbpbYBcUAFLQE4DmL+AlKWIBnYBzjYuAbkoBfajQWKlyhZVQAbWkKFQAsiADCm7QUKUqNeWACuAI3VxUUVDhEdr6TB1Y37jqAC2IAD6oJAs8EhoGDimADRQ8irJir4OTkHBnDxQ-BRyVnbpUAAmmFkMOKx8LG7iXPIWihwQwNYc2FBIcEIAdJlhEL30Mdis3X2Z2XySUAD0c6WYUNiYwM6YAWBw6hDycjKJlLvr4iJZpBQjjCzs3LWi9QIkxNlyJ1BnwMG2NGTk1xwt2yLGw1gCtggHGer24vWAmAAyo8JNV3q1nMYhFlgjhoGRsBAAO56QxY1hfLIJABEACFqQIFhstjs9h8NFpsbZQkTlgTiaSjJyKdhzrYEgBmRmLFws3aUNSuTC7XrqTBcVgc7Q4vG9MoVUbVPgKoA

Comment: It works indeed. However, in my case, I can't modify Class_a and Class_b, so I can't replace them with a class using generics...

Comment: You don't have to modify Class_a - you can lean on structural equivalence (Is entire class_a shown in your example. Is different argument in action the only difference between class_a and class_b?)

Comment: No, class_a have several other members, and class_b also. Some of their members are common, and some are different.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a workaround. The idea is to cast the "action" function inside "do_action()":

```
public do_action(): string
{
     let action = this.my_type.action as (arg: ConditionalArg<T>) => string
     return action(this.my_arg); // compile
}
```

Working example in playground: [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgQwM5IPoKgXgFAG9tRQIDGwAlgPYB2AXFABQIBOA5nUsE2VSwJRYA%20KBy49sAX2zZQkWIhSoARljwEipSrQbM2UKgFcAtoohN%20mISO4sJUmdACiZYAAtT8ZEixzP6KAB8fBUUAbmlwaBhqABNnTQQ4AEFWAB4AFSFMKDSoCAAPYAgqaK8PBQwAfmFOaygaNUJGpuaWxpz8wuLS%20TRlKoNjUzqG1tHWqggAN1Mwsbnm7GIeqABZEDKkdNyCopKoJ1d3HoFVQjB9RTgyYihDEFR7OjTZqHPL69v7nToo4rjqBLJFjpARhNRvK43YjUET6UgUJj0O4PCJPAA0n3QrB%20MX%20VEBqQyvDU%20CarjISAAdMj7N4aREXoRyVTkTo6V9WC9JOCLpCoNEKOgNNR6Lx2DUxIRSY04BBgOpyNRvMzqfd7JSSIqqEQvIxsbBcVqCcCiYJqqIbE0mHL9ExtZrNPQVazWLwQlAAPQeqDQwxgMiytSScRQKSy%20XcDjoH49PxZXAO6h0PW6Kw8cxCHSScNQSPAJQx3zKeOJrQpugDExmM06SnACgAZQlLFF2blPtjCFQ1GgWQmAHdVusevQ8%20gMQAiABCE-4Xp9FD9AYg2HnOaWvi7wH7FG8A6HG1HVCjCAxAGZ%20J7vQK9BR5b7-YG1%202N8FuxM9xBB2tD2PFJOZzna9dyoO8FyXQN11jRQHh3T9v2HTwjyjf8oAvK9wMfFdFhhChZUpOAKBbV80C7HtKQFIUtVFYloWPPCIAIoj6BIpRYIoCjBVLGipCAA)